# Detection of Shelf using OpenCV Java,

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I working on shelf detection , for last one week, still four corner points are not detected , 
here is my code , kindly suggest

```js
public void principalArea( String inputpath ) {
setpath(inputpath);
Mat mat =  Imgcodecs.imread(path);
Mat mat_f = new Mat(mat.size(),CvType.CV_8UC3);
Mat mat_o = new Mat(mat.size(),CvType.CV_8UC3);
Mat mat_n = new Mat(mat.size(),CvType.CV_8UC3);
//Mat morphingMatrix = Mat.ones(3,3, CvType.CV_8UC1);
Mat morphingMatrix = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(3,3));
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mat, mat_f,new Size(9,9),0);
System.out.println(" MAT_F DETAILS GaussianBlur " + mat_f.size() + "," + mat_f.channels());
Imgproc.cvtColor(mat_f, mat_f, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mat_f, mat_f,new Size(15,15),15);
Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(mat_f, mat_f, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2);
Imgproc.morphologyEx(mat_f, mat_f, Imgproc.MORPH_OPEN, morphingMatrix);
Imgproc.Canny(mat_f, mat_f, 100, 400, 5, true);
mat_o=getHoughTransform(mat_f,mat,1,Math.PI/360,80);
System.out.println(" MAT_F DETAILS hough " + mat_o.size() + "," + mat_o.channels());
Imgcodecs.imwrite("Output_0055.jpg",mat_o);
}

public Mat getHoughTransform(Mat image,Mat mat, double rho, double theta, int threshold) {
    Mat result = new Mat(image.size(),CvType.CV_8UC1);
    Mat lines = new Mat();
    int minLineSize = 50, lineGap=90,noofline=1 ;
    double Maxdistance=0.0,Currdistance=0.0, Avgdistance=0.0;
    double maxX1=0,maxY1=0,minX1=image.width(),minY1=image.height(),
           maxX2=0,maxY2=0,minX2=image.width(),minY2=image.height(),
           avgX1=0,avgY1=0,avgX2,avgY2=0;
    Imgproc.HoughLinesP(image, lines, rho, theta, threshold, minLineSize, lineGap);
    for (int x = 0; x < lines.rows(); x++) 
    {
          double[] vec = lines.get(x,0);
          double x1 = vec[0], 
                 y1 = vec[1],
                 x2 = vec[2],
                 y2 = vec[3];
          Point p1 = new Point(x1, y1);
          Point p2 = new Point(x2, y2);
          double angel = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan((y1 - y2) /(x1-x2)));
          if ( -10.00 > angel | angel > 10.00 ) //// filtering line based on slope
          {   System.out.println(" Bypass" + x1 +","+ y1+","+ x2+","+ y2 + " ANGEL IS " + angel);
              continue;
          }
          if ( x1 < 0.02*image.width()  | x2 > (image.width()*(1-0.01))) // filtering line based on position
          {   System.out.println(" Bypasse line at edge" + x1 +","+ y1+","+ x2+","+ y2 + " ANGEL IS " + angel);
              continue;
          }
    Currdistance=euclideanDistance(p1,p2);
    if ( Currdistance < Avgdistance*0.5 ){ continue; } // filtering line based on length          
          if ( Currdistance > Maxdistance ) { Maxdistance = Currdistance ;}           
          Imgproc.line(result, p1, p2, new Scalar(255,255,255), 3);
          Avgdistance = (noofline * Avgdistance + Currdistance )/(++noofline);
          maxX1=(x1>maxX1)?x1:maxX1;minX1=(x1<minX1)?x1:minX1;
          maxY1=(y1>maxY1)?y1:maxY1;minY1=(y1<minY1)?y1:minY1;
          maxX2=(x2>maxX2)?x2:maxX2;minX2=(x2<minX2)?x2:minX2;
          maxY2=(y2>maxY2)?y2:maxY2;minY2=(y2<minY2)?y2:minY2;
          System.out.println(" Point , " + x1 +","+ y1+","+ x2+","+ y2 + ", " + angel +" ," + Currdistance );
    }
    Imgcodecs.imwrite("Hough_0055.jpg",result);
    System.out.println("Image width " + mat.width()+" Image hight " + mat.height());
    System.out.println(maxX1+" ," + maxY1+" ," + minX1+" ," + minY1+" ," +maxX2+" ," + maxY2+" ," + minX2+" ," + minY2);
    Point upperLeft  =  new Point(minX1,minY1);
    Point upperRight = new Point(maxX2,minY2);
    Point lowerLeft  =  new Point(minX1,maxY1);
    Point lowerRight = new Point(maxX2,maxY2);
    Imgproc.circle(mat, upperLeft, 50, new Scalar(255,255,0),50);
    Imgproc.circle(mat, upperRight, 50, new Scalar(255,255,0),50);
    Imgproc.circle(mat, lowerLeft, 50, new Scalar(255,255,0),50);
    Imgproc.circle(mat, lowerRight, 50, new Scalar(255,255,0),50);
    return mat;
}

public double euclideanDistance(Point a, Point b){
    double distance = 0.0;
    try{
        if(a != null && b != null){
            double xDiff = a.x - b.x;
            double yDiff = a.y - b.y;
            distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xDiff,2) + Math.pow(yDiff, 2));
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println(" Error while distance calculation" + e);
    }
    return distance;
}
```

I Have applied all my skills , still is not coming correctly. 
CODE FLOW 
1. low pass filtering , 
2. canny, 
3. hough 
4. Vertical line filering using slope
5. filtering based on edge
6. filtering based on length
7. then four point selection 
8. finally printing 
[Hough output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xh1PD.jpg)[Final Out put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr9F5.jpg)

Comment: Corner points are not detected, but does it output anything at all? Are there any intermediate results? Try adding logging statements and track some progress.

Comment: Showing the output images of your code can help us understand what is happening. Please, edit your question with the output images.

Comment: ok i am uploading